# How to iterate with Object Dot Keys and Array Dot Map to display data in a component?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, redux

I have a `React Component` that I am trying to display data in using the `Object.keys()` method and then trying to iterate through the data using `.map()`.

Here is is how `redux-logger` is printing my data out:

```
body: {data: [0: {
 attributes: {
    name: "Text Widget Name",
    category: "PreBuild",
    description: "Text Widget Description",
    "chart-type": "text_widget"
 },
 type: "widget-templates"
}]}
```

What I am trying to do is iterate through a number of these. Here is my react component.

```js
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import React from "react";

class TextWidget extends React.Component { 
  render() {
    const {
      data
    } = this.props;
    const textData = data;
    const textWidgets = Object.keys(textData[0] || [])    
    .map(key => {
      return (
        <div key={key.id} className="tile-head">
          <div className="title-head-content">
            <h3>{key.attributes.name}</h3>
            {key.attributes.description}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
     return (
        <div
          data={textData}
        >
          {textWidgets}
        </div>
     )
  }
}

TextWidget.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array
};

export default TextWidget;
```

I am getting an error message say `key.attributes.name` is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys(textData[0])` will give you the object

```
{
    attributes: {
      name: "Text Widget Name",
      category: "PreBuild",
      description: "Text Widget Description",
      "chart-type": "text_widget"
    },
    type: "widget-templates"
  }
```

And during the iteration `key` will be `attributes` and `type` in your example.

```
Object.keys((textData[0] && textData[0].attributes) || [])    
    .map(key => {
      return (
        <div key={key.id} className="tile-head">
          <div className="title-head-content">
            <h3>{key.name}</h3>
            {key.description}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
```

Should do. Also note that `key` does not have the `id` property.

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is an array, instead of using `Object.keys` you would directly map over the data to render it like

```
const textWidgets = (textData || []).map(key => {
  return (
    <div key={key.id} className="tile-head">
      <div className="title-head-content">
        <h3>{key.attributes.name}</h3>
        {key.attributes.description}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
});
 return (
    <div
      data={textData}
    >
      {textWidgets}
    </div>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `Object.keys(textData[0] || [])` returns two top level properties.

```
key = attributes
key = type
```

```js
const data =  [{
 attributes: {
    name: "Text Widget Name",
    category: "PreBuild",
    description: "Text Widget Description",
    "chart-type": "text_widget"
 },
 type: "widget-templates"
}];

const textData = data;
const textWidgets = Object.keys(textData[0] || [])    
    .map(key => console.log(`key = ${key}`));
```

You need to go one level deeper and specify `.attributes`.

```
const textWidgets = Object.keys(textData[0].attributes || [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys(textData[0]) has value

```
["attributes", "type"]
```

To render the data, you have to run map on textData directly.

In your case it would be:

```
const textWidgets = textData.map((key, index) => {
    return (
        <div key={index} className="tile-head">
          <div className="title-head-content">
            <h3>{key.attributes.name}</h3>
            {key.attributes.description}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
});
```